# CAShapeLayer sublayer of a UIView in a UIScrollView is extremely slow

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, quartz-core, cashapelayer

I have a custom UIView which is supposed to be a round rectangle which, when you begin editing a UILabel inside, the round rectangle will grow its shape (CABasic animation on a CAShapeLayer  mask path and outline path).  So to be clear, the custom UIView is organized like this:

MyCustomView has a ClipView.
ClipView uses drawRect to draw the background of the round rectangle. (clipview == view that gets clipped)

Then, I call the following code to do the CAShapeLayer manipulation:

```
//0. CLIP

shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CGRect shapeRect = self.bounds;
[shapeLayer setBounds:shapeRect];
[shapeLayer setPosition:CGPointMake((shapeRect.size.width)/2.0f, (shapeRect.size.height)/2.0f)];
[shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1.0f] CGColor]];
[shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor] ];
[shapeLayer setLineWidth:1];
[shapeLayer setLineJoin:kCALineJoinRound];
[shapeLayer setOpacity:1];


CGRect shapeLayerPathRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 44.0f);
shapeLayer.path = [self roundRectPathForRectangle:shapeLayerPathRect andRadius:CORNER_RADIUS];
[[self.clipView layer] setMask:shapeLayer];

//1. draw the shaded outline of a round rectangle
outlineLayer = [self topDownShadowShapeLayer]; //setup for my CAShapeLayer, involving shadow stuff, line color, etc
outlineLayer.path = [self roundRectPathForRectangle:shapeLayerPathRect andRadius:CORNER_RADIUS];
[self.clipView.layer addSublayer:outlineLayer];
```

Although the animation the proceeds is the quickest approach (stretching both CAShapeLayers), the entire element (MyCustomView) causes everything to be a lot slower!  For example, UIView animations that go on, also when MyCustomView is inside a ScrollView it is VERY jumpy.

I'm mostly concerned about the UIScrollView problem.  Why is it so choppy for a UIScrollView to translate these layers around?  Is there a good solution / what's another approach that can achieve the same effect?

Comment: What method is your code in?  Where do you call it?

Comment: The method that my code is in is in awakeFromNib / initWithFrame